# Find file in folder and copy to another folder

Tags: shell

I have some files, each named `abc.pdf`, which are in different folders.

How do I write a script to find these files and copy them to another folder, with a different name (`abc1.pdf`)?

Here's what I have:

```
for D in 20110526 20110626 20110726 20110826 20110926 20111026; do 
   find /app/zipbill/Test/Output/$D/PDF/abc.pdf | cp /app/zipbill/Test/Output/$D/PDF/abc.pdf  /test/abc$(date +%m%d%y).pdf;
done
```

Comment: Why do you need the `find` command? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: I dont need a find command, I just need to copy the file. can you please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different slightly different approaches depending on your needs. If you know the file exists in these directories and want gather them in a single folder, you can do the following

```
for D in 20110526 20110626 20110726 20110826 20110926 20111026; do 
   cp /app/zipbill/Test/Output/$D/PDF/abc.pdf /differentFolder/abc$D.pdf;
done
```

This creates files called *abc20110526.pdf*, *abc20110626.pdf*, ... inside the folder */differentFolder/*.

Comment: Hi There,Thanks for your suggestion. But when I go to  /differentFolder/ , there is no file being copied. [zipbill@abc 20111026]$ for D in 20111026; do     cp /app/zipbill/Test/Output/$D/PDF/309145.pdf /app/zipbill/Test/Output/$D/$D_309145.pdf; done
[zipbill@abc 20111026]$ ls -lrt
total 1368
drwxr-xr-x 2 zipbill abillity 688128 May 15  2013 CSV
drwxr-xr-x 2 zipbill abillity 704512 May 15  2013 PDF

Comment: In this case the problem is somewhere else. What directory are you in when you execute these commands? I'm asking because of your `ls -lrt`. Instead, try `ls /app/zipbill/Test/Output/20111026/`, which should give you the conent of your target directory. If, however, you do `ls` from any other directory, it will show you the contents of your current working directory, not of your target directory.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I am at the directory of /app/zipbill/Test/Output/ whe executing this commands. appreciate your advise.

Comment: This looks like it will do what you want. If it doesn't work, you could  try replacing `cp` with `echo`, to make sure the command-line is being generated correctly.

Comment: Ok, as discussed above, please enter `ls /app/zipbill/Test/Output/20110626/` to see the contents of that target directory. You will *not* see the files you copied if you do not enter the full command including the path.